# How can i use a Rest webservice in my wpf client software?

Tags: asp.net, wpf, web-services

I now how to use a soap base ws from adding wsdl address to Project>Add Service Reference...

But how can i use a restful webservice like [THIS](http://blacks.ir/rest/) in my client side software?

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, if you are using MVC or Web-forms you can create an instance of the webservice you created in your code (or code behind) for that matter. Then you would use the object that you created in order to call different methods and what not, but try going http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203052.aspx. It gives a good example of creating and consuming RESTful web services. Another way you could approach it is by looking into Angular JS. Hope this Helps!

Comment: I could be wrong about the first part. It's been a while since I have done it, but regardless the link seems to be pretty helpful...